# Как запустить .bat файл из SQL SERVER 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Перерыл много информации в интернете, но так и не нашел ответа. Мне нужно при добавлении новой строки в таблицу запускать триггер, который будет в свою очередь запускать на компьютере .bat файл. Пробовал через XP_CMDSHELL, но ничего не получилось.

Вот пример

```
DECLARE @CMDSQL VARCHAR(1000)
SET @CMDSQL = '"D:\telegram.bat"'
EXEC xp_CMDShell @CMDSQL
```

Выдает ошибку: "D:\telegram.bat" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обновите свой пост и покажите полный T-SQL, который вы пробовали.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov привел

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky обновил

Comment: Вам необходимо убедиться, что указанный командный файл находится на сервере, где установлен SQL Server. И не на вашем локальном компьютере

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, так SQL Server у меня установлен на компьютере